# How to link to another Excel document using "dynamic" current directory?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to connect various excel files stored in the same folder. After obtain the folder route using formula INFO("Directory"), I want to use this value in my formulas to get data from other files.

Right now my formula looks like this:

```
='C:\Users\userxxx\Desktop\[2011_FileName.xlsx]Summary'!$C$16
```

And I want something like:

```
= INFO("Directory") & [2011_FileName.xlsx]Summary!$C$16
```

or

```
= $A$1 & [2011_FileName.xlsx]Summary!$C$16
```

*where $A$1 have my current path value*

I am trying to modify my formula, but I can not achieve my objective.

**How to link to another file using the dynamic current path info?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx) function, but note that it works only with opened workbooks (there is no easy solution to achive your requirements for closed workbooks without VBA):

```
=INDIRECT("'" & INFO("Directory") & "[2011_FileName.xlsx]Summary'!$C$16")
```

or

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & "[2011_FileName.xlsx]Summary'!$C$16")
```

Comment: This is my previous option, Do you know any way to get the data even when file is closed?

Comment: I know only VBA solution. Do you like it? I can write user defined function for it, than you can call it like `=getValue("path...")`

Comment: I am trying to do it without using macros. Maybe is too ambitious, but I still not thrown in the towel. Thanks!